# Google maps: Reverse geo code call back is not coming

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, apple-maps

I am trying to reverse geocode location of all photos. I am using reverse geocoder method as follows.

```
func fetchLocation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, completion: @escaping (_ location: LocationData?) -> Void) {

        let lockQueue = DispatchQueue(label:"com.LockQueue")
lockQueue.sync{

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate((coordinate), completionHandler: {
                            reverseGeoCodeResponse, _ in
                            if let reverseGeoCodeResponse = reverseGeoCodeResponse, let reverseGeoCode = reverseGeoCodeResponse.firstResult() {
     let locationData = LocationData()
                            locationData.locality = reverseGeoCode.locality
                            locationData.subLocality = reverseGeoCode.subLocality
                            locationData.administrativeArea = reverseGeoCode.administrativeArea
                            locationData.postalCode = reverseGeoCode.postalCode
                            locationData.country = reverseGeoCode.country
                            locationData.latitude = (coordinate.latitude)
                            locationData.longitude = (coordinate.longitude)
                            locationData.isDataFromGoogle = true
                                completion(locationData)

    }
    }

}
}
```

some times this method is not returning me the callback. I did not understand why and one more thing to add this method can be called by multiple threads at same so i am using lockqueue to make sure i dont get into synchronisation issues.

Comment: How are you determining that the completion handler is not being called? I see that you're ignoring any errors that may be generated by that method.

Comment: I am confirming that completion handler is returning because my breakpoint is reaching this point .self.geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate((coordinate), completionHandler: {.  } so that I confirmed . how to handle errors for this method.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved this issue after days of debugging.

I am making GEOCoder as an instance variable using as self.geoCoder now I changed to following

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
// new Code
let geoCoder = GMSGeoCoder()
geoCoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate((coordinate), completionHandler: {
                            reverseGeoCodeResponse, _ in
}
        // OLD code                self.geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate((coordinate), completionHandler: {
                            reverseGeoCodeResponse, _ in
}
}
```

I changed to local variable and creating for each georeverse call.